# Polars Reading Files Causing Errors

Tags: python, data-cleaning, python-polars

Often when reading messy csv files I end up seeing different kind of errors due to inconsistency of the data types in the column, for instance:

```
ComputeError: Could not parse `22.4` as dtype Int64 at column 59.
The current offset in the file is 433793 bytes.
```

When the file/data is not yet familiar, I likely do not know what is the name of the column at 59th position. I'm asking for advice for more efficient process than what I'm currently doing to overcome these kind of issues:

1 - First I read the file with the reader option set to 'infer_schema_length=0' (which reads the data in pl.Utf8 string format). Another option is to use 'ignore_erros = True', but to my understanding it convers the error values to nulls, which is often what I don't want.

2 - As I don't know yet which is the 59th column, I do a for loop to figure it out

```
for i in enumerate(df.columns):
print(i)
```

3 - Once I figured the column name raising the error, then I'll filter the dataframe to find that specific value to identify on which row(s) it appears on:

```
(pl
    .read_csv(file="file_name.csv", infer_schema_length=0)
    .with_row_count()
    .select(
        [
            pl.col("row_nr"),
            pl.col("Error Column Name")
        ])
    .filter(pl.col("Error Column Name") == "22.4")
)
```

Output:

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌────────┬───────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ Error Column Name │
│ ---    ┆ ---               │
│ u32    ┆ str               │
╞════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 842    ┆ 22.4              │
└────────┴───────────────────┘
```

4 - Then depending on the file and case, but I would adjust the value to what it should be "224" or "22" or "23" either in the source of the file or modifying DF and converting all other column datatypes to desired ones.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a easier way to access nth column in Polars than what I do in step 2?
2. Is there a more optimal way of overcoming the values causing the errors?
3. If I read the file and columns as pl.Utf8 and adjust the value causing the error, is there a convenient way to automatically detect the best datatypes for the df's columns after the data has been read rather than manually going column by column?

Comment: Are you specifying dtypes to int when you get the error about 22.4?

Comment: I'm not specifying dtype for any column, so the reader assumes this column to be int type, but encounters to this error when tries to read the float '22.4'. Not 100% sure how Polars defines the column to be Int, maybe the first value it reads?

Comment: It missing from the example above indeed, but how I'm trying to read this specific file is: pl.read_csv(file="file_name.csv"), and then getting this error of "could not parse '22.4' as dtype int". In this case the column contains 503 int like types, 404 null values, and 1 floating point like, this 22.4, so I guess polars is doing good job saying that this looks like int column. However, not sure why it is not being read as floating point column.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html) the default `infer_schema_length` is 100.  That means if you have a column where the first 100 values are safely integers then it's going to assign the data type for that column as integer.  When it gets to a float it'll error out rather than go back and reset the data type.  Ironically, you took the direction of changing that default in the wrong direction to get the result you wanted.

So, instead of doing `pl.read_csv(file="file_name.csv", infer_schema_length=0)` and then manually casting values, just do `pl.read_csv(file="file_name.csv", infer_schema_length=int(1e10))`.  If you still get the error then make `1e10` bigger or if it's too slow then make it smaller.

That answers your Q2.

Q1: You don't need to loop through all the values, you can just do `df.columns[59]` to get column 59.  Also, instead of reading in the whole df just to get column names you can do `pl.read_csv("file_name.csv", n_rows=1)` which will take up a much smaller memory footprint

Q3: Yes/No.  It depends on what you consider convenient and what is in the domain of formats of files you're opening.  If you just want to have a hierarchy of try int, try float, keep utf then you could do:

```
for i in df.columns:
    try:
        df=df.with_column(pl.col(i).cast(pl.Int64()))
        continue
    except:
        pass
    try:
        df=df.with_column(pl.col(i).cast(pl.Float64()))
        continue
    except:
        pass
```